# Query Realm with multiple backlinks

Tags: xamarin, realm

The Realm documentation gives an example of backlinks using a person object and a dog object. If I extend this to include cats also, so a person can have several dogs or cats to walk, and each dog or cat can be walked by several different people.

```cs
public class Dog : RealmObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Backlink(nameof(Person.Dogs))]
    public IQueryable<Person> Walkers { get; }
}

public class Cat : RealmObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Backlink(nameof(Person.Cats))]
    public IQueryable<Person> Walkers { get; }
}

public class Person : RealmObject 
{
    //... other properties (name, age, address, etc.)
    public IList<Dog> Dogs { get; }
    public IList<Cat> Cats { get; }
}
```

Using the backlinks lets me get a list of people who walk the dog Fido...

```cs
var fidoWalkers = realm.All<Dog>().Where( d => d.Name == "Fido").FirstOrDefault().Walkers;
```

I can now further expand this query to find walkers of Fido who live in High Street or who are under 30 years old or whatever... great so far.

Now I want to get a list of people who walk the dog Fido and the cat Moggie. Using the backlinks in two separate statements I could get two result sets, one for Fido walkers and one for Moggie walkers, but I don't know how to combine them. Neither can I work out a query that would let me do this 'the long way round' without using the backlinks, because whenever I try to use

```cs
...Where( P => p.Dogs.Contains(Fido))...
```

I get 'System.NotSupportedException: The method 'Contains' is not supported'

Is there any way to get a list of people filtered by both the Dogs and the Cats lists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there are many things the .Net version of Realm does well, there are limitations in the `Linq` support and thus you are forced to materialize the lazy loaded `IRealmCollection` to a hard `List` (or array) via `LINQ to Objects` in order to perform projections, joins, IEqualityComparer comparisons, etc... this includes Backlinks and RealmObject-based `IList` properties.

A must read `Realm-dotnet` document: [LINQ support in Realm Xamarin](https://realm.io/docs/xamarin/latest/api/linqsupport.html)

You *could* add couple of properties that perform a `Linq` projection to a list of strings (pet names, of course assuming they are unique keys):

```cs
public class Person : RealmObject
{
    //... other properties (name, age, address, etc.)
    public IList<Dog> Dogs { get; }
    public IList<Cat> Cats { get; }

    public List<string> DogList => Dogs.ToList().Select(_ => _.Name).ToList();
    public List<string> CatList => Cats.ToList().Select(_ => _.Name).ToList();
}
```

And then take your person query to a list and use `Contains` on the materialized string lists vs. the RealmCollection properties.

```cs
var walkers = realm.All<Person>().ToList().Where(_ => _.CatList.Contains("Garfield") && _.DogList.Contains("Fido"));
foreach (var walker in walkers)
{
    Log.Debug(TAG, $"{walker}");
}
```

You could also create two queries, one filtered on the dog's name backlink and cats for the other, materialized all the Dog and Cat collections on each Person in both queries, perform a `Distinct` via a custom `IEqualityComparer`.

Once you have copied the objects out of Realm into independent lists/arrays, just about any Linq solution will work...

The downside of this is all the filtering is being performed in memory thus you take a memory and CPU hit as you are not able to use Realm's native query features...

Personally, I would re-model the `RealmObject`'s to provide people that walk animals and thus animals are generic and they in turn provide links to particular Dog and Cat RealmObjects that provide specialization. But that is totally without knowing your end goal...

Comment: Great answer thankyou - now I have a much better understanding. My actual models are obviously considerably more complex (actually a catalogue of sewing pattern objects, each with multiple garment types, fabric types, categories and tags etc.) but I will look at the practicalities of changing the model structure versus the speed/memory hit of running LINQ queries on in-memory lists. Some more experimentation needed...

Comment: @sparks No problem, Personally I think one of the things required for optimal memory/CPU usage when using Realm is the ability to design your Realm model that fits your app usage pattern. When a client says the model can *not* change **period**, I lean towards SQLite. When we have the freedom to re-think the model from an App usage viewpoint, Realm can be amazing in terms of performance, usage of "live" objects, etc... but usually the original model ends (highly) de-normalized and we create a data map on the server to handle the JSON serialization/deserialization...

Comment: @sparks In terms of `app usage pattern`, I look at what is displayed per Page, screen, table, Activity, Fragment, UITableView, etc... and that is the start of my Realm model for each and every app view. If it isn't shown on the screen, sorted by, or a primary/hidden key used for the API/sync/etc... I do not include it. After every way the data is shown within the app is known, it becomes "easy" ;-) to model all those small model fragments into a consolidated de-normalized  model that is highly performant.... App versions that change the model are handle via Realm migrations.

Comment: The app is a catalogue of users' sewing patterns, its major use case is finding a desired pattern by filtering and searching to narrow down the displayed list of patterns. Each pattern has one or more garment types, one or more tags, one or more fabric types, etc. Each is just a text description, though because Realm does not support lists of primitives I was using a list or GarmentType realm objects (which also gave me backlinking), etc.. [...continued]

Comment: [cont...] In order to query all patterns with this garment type or that garment type and this tag or that tag, would I be better off storing the garment types/tags as comma delimited strings rather than lists, and using string.contains in my query, since querying lists seems difficult. This might be more efficient than materialising to a hard list? I have a green field and would welcome any advice on model representation that facilitates such filter and search fucntions.

Comment: @sparks FYI: Lists of primitives in Realm is coming, it was released in Realm Core (the C++ core library) at the end of July in RC2(?), and will eventually make it into each platform as it has been a requested features for *years*... Realm-dotnet has a PR that was being merged two weeks ago so I'm *assuming* the next release will include it (`v2.0`?).  As far as your data model concerns, I need coffee to think about it... ;-)